# How do I print this returned value in php?

Tags: php

```
function printmsg($string,$type) {//type 1 = green, type 2 = red
    if($type == 1) $msg = "<p style=\"color:#00C5CD\">".$string."</p>";
    if($type == 2) $msg = "<p style=\"color:#f7110b\">".$string."</p>";
    return $msg;
}
printmsg("hello",1);

//lots of other code
print($msg);
```

Im trying to get my returned value to print but it never seems to work.

Comment: Assign the result of the function to a variable then print. `$variable = printmsg("hello",1); echo($variable);` or you can print it directly `echo(printmsg("hello",1))`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about saving the return of the function in a variable and printing the variable

```
function printmsg($string,$type) {//type 1 = green, type 2 = red
    if($type == 1) $msg = "<p style=\"color:#00C5CD\">".$string."</p>";
    if($type == 2) $msg = "<p style=\"color:#f7110b\">".$string."</p>";
    return $msg;
}
$msg = printmsg("hello",1);

//lots of other code
print($msg);
```

Comment: The `$msg` in `printmsg` is only available in `printmsg`, http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: He might confuse $msg in function and $msg outside the function.

Answer (score 1):

if you are returning something you must have to catch it in some variables. Also in `PHP` you need to use `echo` to print the variables.

```
function printmsg($string,$type) {//type 1 = green, type 2 = red
    if($type == 1) $msg = "<p style=\"color:#00C5CD\">".$string."</p>";
    if($type == 2) $msg = "<p style=\"color:#f7110b\">".$string."</p>";
    return $msg;
}
$msg = printmsg("hello",1);

//lots of other code
echo $msg;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just echo it

```
function printmsg($string,$type) {//type 1 = green, type 2 = red
    if($type == 1) $msg = "<p style=\"color:#00C5CD\">".$string."</p>";
    if($type == 2) $msg = "<p style=\"color:#f7110b\">".$string."</p>";
    return $msg;
}
echo printmsg("hello",1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
function printmsg($string,$type) {//type 1 = green, type 2 = red
if($type == 1) $msg = "<p style=\"color:#00C5CD\">".$string."</p>";
if($type == 2) $msg = "<p style=\"color:#f7110b\">".$string."</p>";
return $msg;
```

}
$msg=printmsg("hello",1);

//lots of other code
print($msg);